# How can I change a label in a different class with an UIPickerView

Tags: ios, swift

I wanna use a UIPickerView to change a label on another ViewController. That means in another class. How can I do it? How could the code look like? I think my problem is easy to fix, but I am quite new to this programming language.

I already tried several things, but nothing worked.

Comment: What did you try ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Delegates or Notifications.
Delegate is preferred for cases like these. here's an example:

This is the class that holds the picker (assuming you have a `values` array that represents the content of your picker):

```
protocol PickerControllerDelegate: class {
   func pickerControllerDidChangeValue(value: String?)
}

class PickerViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate {
   var values: [String] = []
   weak var delegate: PickerControllerDelegate?

   func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
          let value = self.values[row] as? String
          self.delegate.pickerControllerDidChangeValue(value: value)
       }
}
```

And this is the other `ViewController` that listens to the changes of the picker:

```
class OtherViewController: UIViewController, PickerControllerDelegate {

   override viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      let instanceOfPickerViewContoller = PickerViewController()
      instanceOfPickerViewContoller.delegate = self
   }

   // MARK - PickerViewController Delegate
   func pickerControllerDidChangeValue(value: String?) {
       // Now you have the new value!
   }
}
```

Comment: Will segues help in this case @Lirik? The prepareForSegue function?

Comment: @ojassethi If you need to update the UI in OtherViewController, yes prepareForSegue or viewWillAppear will be good places to place that code.